# give space above and below a DIV

Tags: css

I want to give a DIV space above and under its content.

How can I do this using CSS?

my DIV code is:

```
<div class="input">
    <label for="pseudo">choisir un pseudo*:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="pseudo">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you already tried anything? `margin` and/or `padding` tend to be the usual properties to set.

Comment: @adamdunson `margin` doesn't set space above and below an element **content** but rather between two different elements.

Comment: @Sunyatasattva Sure. I was referring to adding space in the general sense. The question is not incredibly clear.

Comment: @adamdunson Well, indeed. I wanted to make sure that future searchers don't get confused by this simple fact. As a matter of fact, `margin` is still part of the element box itself, so not really empty space between two elements, but to people searching/asking for this kind of basic questions, it might be more useful to visualize it like so. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You use the CSS [**`padding` property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/padding). In your case you might want to use `padding-top`and `padding-bottom` alone.

The syntax is the following:

```
padding: top right bottom left;
```

or

```
padding: vertical horizontal;
```

Some examples:

```
// This will set the top space to 1px, the right to 2px the bottom to 3px
// and the left to 4px
.input {
    padding: 1px 2px 3px 4px;
}

// This will set both the top and the bottom to 20px and the right and the
// left to 10px;
.input {
    padding: 20px 10px;
}

// This will set only the bottom space, leaving everything else
// to be automatically determined
.input {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

**Read more about the [HTML Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)**

Comment: I was too slow, and this answer is more thorough! :)

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure what you mean. Space within or on the outside?

Assuming you mean on the outside:

```
.input {
   margin: 20px 0;
}
```

If you mean within the div then padding is the one to use.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for padding.

```
<div class="input" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px">
  <label for="pseudo">choisir un pseudo*:</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="pseudo">
</div>
```

Hope it helps, Viggo

Answer (score 1):

In case you want additional space ( more than the default ) between div rows then you can add the following code before/after the start of the div row depending on where you want the additional space.

```
<div class="row">
   </br>
 </div>
```

This is easier but will add a fixed amount of gap. If you want the gap to be more specific then you can use the padding options described above.